# How to call a function when the closure return value is not needed

Tags: swift, closures

I wrote a function with an escaping variable

```
func getData(data: PSData, otherParams: [String], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

Usually i call it this way

```
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

If I don't need the response, is it correct to call the function in this way? Or is there any simplification that couod be made

```
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) { (_) in }
```

Comment: try default value func getData(data: PSData, otherParams: [String], completion:@escaping((Bool) -> Void))? = nil)

Comment: and call like ->  getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct:

```
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) { _ in }
```

but it's little bit cleaner when you pass `nil` (not typing this ugly braces) or use `nil` as default value:

```
func getData(data: PSData, otherParams: [String], completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams, completion: nil)
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) // shorter version
```

`UIKit` use similar way:

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error with your code "@escaping attribute only applies to function types"

Comment: @user567, hi, sure, there is no need to use `@escaping` right here. bad copypaste. updated the answer.

Comment: You can have an empty completion as a default parameter, too: `func getData(data: Int, otherParams: [String], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in })`. You can use the shorter version with this but you can't explicitly pass `nil` as the `completion:` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write function something like:

```
func getData(data: PSData, otherParams: [String], completion: ((Bool) -> ())?) {

}

getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams, completion: nil)
```

OR

```
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the brackets:

```
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams) { _ in }
```

...or if the function is your own and customizable, you can provide a default value for the closure and you can leave it out altogether:

```
func getData(data: PSData, otherParams: [String], completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void = { _ in })
[...]
getData(data: myData, otherParams: myOtherParams)
```

Comment: I got an error with your suggestion and xCode suggested me to use completion:@escaping(Bool) -> Void = { _ in }) . Is this equivalent to your code?